# Mac - cannot find Eigen3

Tags: cmake, homebrew, eigen

I am trying to build [TheiaSfM](http://www.theia-sfm.org/building.html).

I build it with this command

```
cmake -DBUILD_DOCUMENTATION=ON -DEIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR=$EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR ..
```

where I set `EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/eigen/3.2.9/include/`. This is the path to `Eigen` in my computer.

But I got this error:

```
CMake Error at cmake/FindEigen.cmake:77 (message):
  Failed to find Eigen - Could not find file:
  /usr/local/Cellar/eigen/3.2.9/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/Macros.h
  containing version information in Eigen install located at:
  /usr/local/Cellar/eigen/3.2.9/include.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/FindEigen.cmake:123 (eigen_report_not_found)
  CMakeLists.txt:108 (find_package)
```

I guess this is trivial, but I already tried to search but cannot really understand the problem. I am really new to this, so, any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your error message, your program cannot find where the dir "Eigen" is. I guess it is in

```
/usr/local/Cellar/eigen/3.2.9/
```

Have you looked if there really is a sub-dir "include" in the above path? Official source code does not have this sub-dir.

---

So now you find that the dir `Eigen` is in

```
/usr/local/Cellar/eigen/3.2.9/include/eigen3
```

As for the version issue, you could go to Eigen's website and download the desired version.

http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page

Comment: Ok. Solved the problem. It should be `EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/eigen/3.2.9/include/eigen3`. But got new error 
`Failed to find Ceres - Found Eigen dependency, but the version of Eigen found (3.2.9) does not exactly match the version of Eigen Ceres was compiled with (3.2.8).` And `CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:152 (find_package):
      Found package configuration file:

        /usr/local/share/Ceres/CeresConfig.cmake

      but it set Ceres_FOUND to FALSE`

Comment: I am brewing this, so, really kind of overwhelmed with all of this.

Comment: You could download v3.2.8 from the official website.